# LogiOptionsMgr.exe Logition Options software is blocked from sending data from my PC

Tags: windows, mouse, firewall, logitech-mouse, wireless-mouse

**TL;DR / Question: How to enable an app to use internet and send packets on Windows 10? Other than FireWall what else could block a process from accessing internet?**

Hello,

I recently bought a [Logitech MX Master 3](https://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/mx-master-3?crid=7) mouse, which somehow is not connecting with my 3rd computer, from other 2 machines. I am trying to activate Logitech Flow to control 3 of my computers, but it is current only working with only 2 of my machines.

Finding no help from customer-care I thought of doing the diagnostics from my end.

Upon using [SysInternal Suite](http://live.sysinternals.com/)'s Process Monitor on the process LogiOptionsMgr.exe, I get the following traces, where I see that the process only receives packets but cannot sending any, and that's basically the problem is.

[image]

Now to enable send, I have disabled all my firewall (controlled by McAfee AV) but still that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the problem was somewhere else. I was using my Hyper-V manager, which chages my switch to a internal switch and for that reason the Logi Options App cannot find my 3rd device.

Disabling that Hyper-V virtual Switch solved solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone else having the same problem:
I just got me the MX Master 3 and Keys and was hoping to use Flow as advertised for switching between a MBP and Win 10 machines.
Initially I experienced the same problems for Flow not finding other computers in the network. I use both the the Unifying Receiver.
I checked both computers for open ports and connectivity between them with NetCat, both checked out Ok yet still Flow wasn't able to find each other.
The culprit was the Win 10 machine. Specifically McAfee Endpoint Security. Once I disabled the Endpoint Security Firewall and restarted Flow on the Win machine it was able to find and "flow" between computers both mouse and keyboard.
---UPDATE---
McAfee will automatically enable the Endpoint Security Firewall after a while, be sure to figure out a way to add exceptions to allow for Flow to work properly.